# Show distinct values with the node

Tags: xml, xquery

when I try to output diferent name and surname of authors my code doesn't output the node.

```
    distinct-values(
  for $b in doc("book.xml")//book/author
order by $b/name, $b/surname
return <author>{string($b/name), string($b/surname)}</author>
)
```

With this xml.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
<bib>
    <book year="1994">
        <title>TCP/IP Illustrated</title>
        <author>
            <surname>Stevens</surname>
            <name>W.</name>
        </author>
        <editorial>Addison-Wesley</editorial>
        <price> 65.95</price>
    </book>

    <book year="1992">
        <title>Advan Programming for Unix environment</title>
        <author>
            <surname>Stevens</surname>
            <name>W.</name>
        </author>
        <editorial>Addison-Wesley</editorial>
        <price>65.95</price>
    </book>

     <book year="2000">
        <title>Millenium</title>
        <author>
            <surname>Falk</surname>
            <name>Lombardo</name>
        </author>
        <editorial>Morgan Kaufmann editorials</editorial>
        <price>19.50</price>
    </book>

    <book year="2000">
        <title>Data on the Web</title>
        <author>
            <surname>Abiteboul</surname>
            <name>Serge</name>
        </author>
        <author>
            <surname>Buneman</surname>
            <name>Peter</name>
        </author>
        <author>
            <surname>Suciu</surname>
            <name>Dan</name>
        </author>
        <editorial>Morgan Kaufmann editorials</editorial>
        <price>39.95</price>
    </book>


    <book year="1999">
        <title> Economics of Technology for Digital TV</title>
        <editor>
          <surname>Gerbarg</surname>
            <name>Darcy</name>
          <afiliacion>CITI</afiliacion>
        </editor>
        <editorial>Kluwer Academic editorials</editorial>
        <price>129.95</price>
    </book>
</bib>
```

The following code outputs:

```
Dan Suciu
Lombardo Falk
Peter Buneman
Serge Abiteboul
W. Stevens
```

But I want to get:

```
<author>Dan Suciu</author>
<author>Lombardo Falk</author>
<author>Peter Buneman</author>
<author>Serge Abiteboul</author>
<author>W. Stevens</author>
```

Could someone tell me what I am doing wrong ? thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `distinct-values()` expects and returns a sequence of atomic values, i.e. your `<author/>` elements are converted into a string first.

So instead you want to get your distinct names first and convert them to an element later. Something like this should return the expected result:

```
for $name in distinct-values(
  for $b in doc("book.xml")//book/author
  order by $b/name, $b/surname
  return string-join(($b/name, $b/surname), " ")
)
return <author>{ $name }</author>
```

Comment: I think it's perfectly what I wanted but I didn't realize how could it be, thanks, now the problem that I'm getting is that it's sorting by surname so I'm getting on first place the surname and then the name, How can I inverse the output from "Suciu Dan" to "Dan Suciu" ?

Comment: @TrnChristian sorry, fixed it, my mistake